# Random "MessagingException: Failed to load IMAP envelope" looping throught Messages (server mail IMAP protocol bug)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm getting this random exception while looping through the Messages of my mailServer (is a hMailServer on local network):

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Failed to load IMAP envelope
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadEnvelope(IMAPMessage.java:1532)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getSubject(IMAPMessage.java:441)
```

it happen while I for-loop the `Message[]` array from the server

The scope of (this part) of the Java program is pretty simple:

- Read all Messages from the Inbox
- Read Subject
- Move to correct Folder

I've alredy tried this know fix: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#imapserverbug  (both the methods described)

the `moveFromFolderTo()` is where I apply the fix:

```
public static Message moveFromFolderTo(Message mail, String sourceFolder, String DestinationFolder) {

        try {
    //this is the javaMailFAQ fix
            MimeMessage tmp = new MimeMessage((MimeMessage) mail);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            tmp.writeTo(bos);
            bos.close();
            SharedByteArrayInputStream bis = new SharedByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
            MimeMessage cmsg = new MimeMessage(session, bis);
    //this is the javaMailFAQ fix

            List<Message> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            tempList.add(cmsg);
            Message[] tempMessageArray = tempList.toArray(new Message[tempList.size()]);

            Folder srcFolder = store.getFolder(sourceFolder);
            srcFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            Folder destFolder = store.getFolder(DestinationFolder);
            destFolder.appendMessages(tempMessageArray);
            mail.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
            srcFolder.close(true);

            return cmsg;
```

the `Message` retrieved is the simplest for-loop:

```
Message messages[] = inboxFolder.getMessages();
```

but doesn't work, at random Message it crashes; the mailServer log doesn't help, at some point:

```
//for-loop start, Messages[] alredy fetched 
A8 FETCH 2 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE)
A8 OK FETCH completed
javax.mail.MessagingException: Failed to load IMAP envelope
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadEnvelope(IMAPMessage.java:1532)
```

any help?

Made another test without the JavaMail-FAQ fix, looks like mailServer and clients are "out of synch":

```
Mails in folder: 6  //mails from getMessages.length
cycle-step : 1
mailSubject: test4

cycle-step : 2
mailSubject: test
moveToWorking ex:java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 > 1
moveToWorking ex:java.lang.NullPointerException

cycle-step : 3
mailSubject: test4
moveToWorking ex:java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 > 2
moveToWorking ex:java.lang.NullPointerException

cycle-step :4
//after some mail the usual Exception
javax.mail.MessagingException: Failed to load IMAP envelope
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadEnvelope(IMAPMessage.java:1532)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getSubject(IMAPMessage.java:441)
    at com.horsa.antidatacap.main.Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

but consider that from Thunderbird i can see only 4 email in my inbox

full debug log (`session.setDebug(true);`) for this case:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.2
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: enable STARTTLS
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "192.168.75.131", port 993, isSSL true
* OK IMAPrev1
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=192.168.75.131, user=sourceMail@host.net, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism PLAIN not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism NTLM not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism XOAUTH2 disabled by property: mail.imaps.auth.xoauth2.disable
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command result: A1 OK LOGIN completed
A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk
A2 OK CAPABILITY completed
DEBUG IMAPS: connection available -- size: 1
A3 SELECT SourceFolder
* 4 EXISTS
* 2 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1561546646] current uidvalidity
* OK [UIDNEXT 83] next uid
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)] limited
A3 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed
Mails in folder: 4  //mails from getMessages.length
cycle-step : 1
A4 FETCH 1 (FLAGS)
* 1 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen))
A4 OK FETCH completed
A5 FETCH 1 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE)
* 1 FETCH (RFC822.SIZE 625 INTERNALDATE "28-Jun-2019 12:57:18 +0200" ENVELOPE ("Fri, 28 Jun 2019 12:57:18 +0200" "email1" (("Surname, name" NIL "sender" "host.net")) (("Surname, name" NIL "sender" "host.net")) (("Surname, name" NIL "sender" "host.net")) (("sourceMail@host.net" NIL "destiMail" "host.net")) NIL NIL NIL "<e5020a7f-70de-1b4d-1f8f-3db139ce35a9@host.net>"))
A5 OK FETCH completed
A6 FETCH 1 (BODY[]<0.16384>)
* 1 FETCH (BODY[]<0> {625}
Return-Path: sender@host.net
Received: from [192.168.75.96] (******.*********.net [192.168.75.96])
    by INFINITYHR with ESMTPA
    ; Fri, 28 Jun 2019 12:56:08 +0200
To: sourceMail@host.net
From: "Surname, name" <sender@host.net>
Subject: email1
Message-ID: <e5020a7f-70de-1b4d-1f8f-3db139ce35a9@host.net>
Date: Fri, 28 Jun 2019 12:57:18 +0200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101
 Thunderbird/60.7.2
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Language: en-US




)
A6 OK FETCH completed
DEBUG IMAPS: no connections in the pool, creating a new one
* OK IMAPrev1
B0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk
B0 OK CAPABILITY completed
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism PLAIN not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism NTLM not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism XOAUTH2 disabled by property: mail.imaps.auth.xoauth2.disable
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command result: B1 OK LOGIN completed
B2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk
B2 OK CAPABILITY completed
B3 SELECT SourceFolder
* 4 EXISTS
* 2 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1561546646] current uidvalidity
* OK [UIDNEXT 83] next uid
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)] limited
B3 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed
DEBUG IMAPS: no connections in the pool, creating a new one
* OK IMAPrev1
C0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk
C0 OK CAPABILITY completed
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism PLAIN not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism NTLM not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism XOAUTH2 disabled by property: mail.imaps.auth.xoauth2.disable
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command result: C1 OK LOGIN completed
C2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk
C2 OK CAPABILITY completed
C3 SELECT tempFolder
* 2 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1561724024] current uidvalidity
* OK [UIDNEXT 28] next uid
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)] limited
C3 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed
B4 COPY 1 tempFolder
B4 OK COPY completed
A7 STORE 1 +FLAGS (\Deleted)
* 1 FETCH (FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen) UID 78)
A7 OK STORE completed
B5 CLOSE
* 1 FETCH (FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen) UID 78)
B5 OK CLOSE completed
DEBUG IMAPS: added an Authenticated connection -- size: 1
DEBUG IMAP: pool is full, not adding an Authenticated connection
C4 CLOSE
* 3 EXISTS
* 3 RECENT
C4 OK CLOSE completed
C5 LOGOUT
* BYE Have a nice day
C5 OK Logout completed
cycle-step : 2
A8 FETCH 2 (FLAGS)
* 2 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen))
A8 OK FETCH completed
A9 FETCH 2 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE)
* 2 FETCH (RFC822.SIZE 627 INTERNALDATE "28-Jun-2019 12:57:30 +0200" ENVELOPE ("Fri, 28 Jun 2019 12:57:30 +0200" "email3" (("Surname, name" NIL "sender" "host.net")) (("Surname, name" NIL "sender" "host.net")) (("Surname, name" NIL "sender" "host.net")) (("sourceMail@host.net" NIL "destiMail" "host.net")) NIL NIL NIL "<2bb18768-1d40-d56c-c946-480127a6a660@host.net>"))
A9 OK FETCH completed
A10 FETCH 2 (BODY[]<0.16384>)
* 2 FETCH (BODY[]<0> {627}
Return-Path: sender@host.net
Received: from [192.168.75.96] (******.*********.net [192.168.75.96])
    by INFINITYHR with ESMTPA
    ; Fri, 28 Jun 2019 12:56:21 +0200
To: sourceMail@host.net
From: "Surname, name" <sender@host.net>
Subject: email3
Message-ID: <2bb18768-1d40-d56c-c946-480127a6a660@host.net>
Date: Fri, 28 Jun 2019 12:57:30 +0200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101
 Thunderbird/60.7.2
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Language: en-US





)
A10 OK FETCH completed
DEBUG IMAPS: connection available -- size: 1
B6 SELECT SourceFolder
* 3 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1561546646] current uidvalidity
* OK [UIDNEXT 83] next uid
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)] limited
B6 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed
DEBUG IMAPS: no connections in the pool, creating a new one
* OK IMAPrev1
D0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk
D0 OK CAPABILITY completed
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism PLAIN not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism NTLM not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism XOAUTH2 disabled by property: mail.imaps.auth.xoauth2.disable
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command result: D1 OK LOGIN completed
D2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk
D2 OK CAPABILITY completed
D3 SELECT tempFolder
* 2 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1561724024] current uidvalidity
* OK [UIDNEXT 29] next uid
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)] limited
D3 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed
B7 COPY 2 tempFolder
B7 OK COPY completed
A11 STORE 2 +FLAGS (\Deleted)
* 2 FETCH (FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen) UID 81)
A11 OK STORE completed
B8 CLOSE
* 2 FETCH (FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen) UID 81)
B8 OK CLOSE completed
DEBUG IMAPS: added an Authenticated connection -- size: 1
DEBUG IMAP: pool is full, not adding an Authenticated connection
D4 CLOSE
* 3 EXISTS
* 3 RECENT
D4 OK CLOSE completed
D5 LOGOUT
* BYE Have a nice day
D5 OK Logout completed
cycle-step : 3
A12 FETCH 3 (FLAGS)
A12 OK FETCH completed
A13 FETCH 3 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE)
A13 OK FETCH completed
moveToWorking ex:javax.mail.MessagingException: Failed to load IMAP envelope
javax.mail.MessagingException: Failed to load IMAP envelope
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadEnvelope(IMAPMessage.java:1532)
cycle-step : 4
A14 FETCH 4 (FLAGS)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getSize(IMAPMessage.java:511)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.<init>(MimeMessage.java:245)
    at com.horsa.antidatacap.utilities.MailHandler.moveFromFolderTo(MailHandler.java:100)
    at com.horsa.antidatacap.main.Main.main(Main.java:31)
A14 OK FETCH completed
A15 FETCH 4 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE)
A15 OK FETCH completed
moveToWorking ex:javax.mail.MessagingException: Failed to load IMAP envelope
javax.mail.MessagingException: Failed to load IMAP envelope
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadEnvelope(IMAPMessage.java:1532)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getSize(IMAPMessage.java:511)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.<init>(MimeMessage.java:245)
    at com.horsa.antidatacap.utilities.MailHandler.moveFromFolderTo(MailHandler.java:100)
    at com.horsa.antidatacap.main.Main.main(Main.java:31)
fine
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore cleanup, force false
DEBUG IMAPS: close folder
DEBUG IMAP: pool is full, not adding an Authenticated connection
A16 LOGOUT
* BYE Have a nice day
A16 OK Logout completed
B9 LOGOUT
* BYE Have a nice day
B9 OK Logout completed
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore cleanup done
```

Comment: It looks like your mail server is failing to provide the requested information for a message.  That's probably a bug in the mail server.  Are multiple applications accessing the mailbox at the same time?

Comment: Nop, this mailserver is on our local network and is used just for development/testing, at the time i'm the only one working on it; but sometimes with thunderbird looks like the are less/more nuber of email fetched by the client or by JavaMail (Ex: i see 3 mails from Thunderbird but i get 4 emails from the inboxFolder.getMessages();) other times seems like the mailserver don't acctually purge the messages with the DELETE flag

Comment: Try splitting the loop so that first a loop retrieves data. Then another loop deletes (and expunges). If that works, the problem was that the mailbox was being modified, e.g. an expunge being issued by thunderbird, and you were expecting something to remain unchanged.

Comment: made some other test, edited main thread

Comment: @arnt is already splitted, i do the .getMessages() outside and then for-loop the Message[], ih this loop there is the moveFromFolderTo method

Comment: What mail server are you using?  Can you post the entire JavaMail debug output?  Is Thunderbird being used to access the mailbox at the same time your program is running?

Comment: i'm using hMailServer, and Thunderbird is not used while executing the program;
edited main thread with full log.
could be that is the java program that bring the server in that inconsistent state? looks like the server goes in that state only after the first exception.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least had to change mail server, i finally get it to work with Apache James; maybe a little more complicated than hMailServer but surly more stable.

https://james.apache.org/server/3/quick-start.html